# Que veut dire « doxa » ?

Tags: sens

[Cet article](http://www.lemonde.fr/tunisie/article/2011/12/18/marzouki-les-francais-sont-prisonniers-d-une-doxa-au-sujet-de-l-islam_1620214_1466522.html#ens_id=1245377) sur *Le Monde* a pour titre « Marzouki : “Les Français sont prisonniers d'une doxa au sujet de l'islam” ».  Je ne peux pas trouver le sens du mot *doxa* — il veut dire quoi ?

Comment: Les articles [wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doxa) ne te satisfont pas ?

Comment: Et autres dictionnaires en ligne. De plus on dit aussi *doxa* en anglais, en espagnol, en beaucoup d'autres langues... facile à trouver quand même.

Comment: On *peut* dire "doxa" en anglais, mais ce n'est pas un [mot](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/doxa) [commun](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/doxa).  :-)

Comment: Il n'est pas plus employé en français qu'en anglais. L'expression courante en français -en dehors des discussions philosophiques- est "opinion dominante".

Comment: The english translation might be something like 'the received (or conventional) wisdom'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Selon [Wikipadia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doxa)

> La doxa est l'ensemble – plus ou moins homogène – d'opinions (confuses
>   ou non), de préjugés populaires ou singuliers, de présuppositions
>   généralement admises et évaluées positivement ou négativement, sur
>   lesquelles se fonde toute forme de communication...

D'après le Petit Robert :

> Ensemble d'opinions communément admises dans une société donnée. (1970 Barthes).

Answer (score 4):

Le Dictionnaire de l'Académie française (neuvième édition papier) ne donne pas directement Doxa mais:

- Dox(o) - Emprunté du grec *doxo-*, élément de composition tiré de *doxa*, "jugement, croyance, gloire".
  Elément de composition signifiant *Opinion, croyance, réputation* ou *forme inférieure du savoir*.

Answer (score 2):

Le synonyme d'usage courant et de même étymologie est *doctrine*.

Cela dit, dans le contexte je pense que le sens du mot est plus proche de *préjugés*.

Answer (score 1):

Voici ce que j'ai relevé à propos de ce mot :

une doxa : l'opinion commune, l'idéologie d'une époque ; pour une civilisation donnée, l'ensemble des opinions communes à ses membres, considérées comme évidentes, qui s'imposent sans discussion et sans avoir besoin d'être étayées par des arguments.

elle, il est doxique : est de l'ordre de l'opinion, de la croyance ; est relative, relatif à la doxa.

une doxocratie : un système politique régi par l'opinion, où règnent les sondages, les modes médiatiques, les pensées dominantes, et qui se traduit par une forme de populisme.

une, un doxographe : une autrice, un auteur de compilations relatives aux philosophes anciens.

une doxographie : une connaissance des opinions, des doctrines ; une compilation qui s'y rapporte.

elle, il est doxographique : a trait à la doxographie.

une doxologie : une parole, un discours qui correspond à l'opinion dominante ou généralement admise, la doxa ; une formule de louanges utilisée dans la liturgie chrétienne, pour célébrer la gloire de Dieu.

elle, il est doxologique : a trait à une doxologie.

une, un doxosophe : celle, celui qui se consacre à la transmission d'une doxa sans jamais la remettre en cause, par opposition aux philosophes ; une faiseuse d'opinion, un faiseur d'opinion", qui, par sondages interposés, interviennent dans les médias pour diffuser une pensée censée représenter celle de l'opinion publique.

la doxosophie : l'art de transmettre une doxa au peuple.

Le nom (une) doxa est emprunté au grec « opinion, avis ».

Le nom (une) doxologie est emprunté au grec δ ο ξ ο λ ο γ ι ́ α « glorification, hymne de louanges ».